# How can I remove windows right click menu?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a group of text boxes within my form. Whenever I right click on them or the panel they are in, I get this menu:

[image]

I want to remove this menu from showing, and leave the right click to be nothing. However, the mouseclick event never fires for any of these. Therefore, I am having trouble getting rid of it. It usually shows up when my text is highlighted.

Is there a way to remove it? Or am I looking in the wrong event?

Comment: add a ctm to your form (or instance one), dont add any items to it, then assign it to the Text controls

Comment: Textbox.mouseclick events

Comment: @Plutonix it took me a second to realize that "ctm" meant contextmenu. hah! Monday morning indeed.

Comment: actually a contextmenustrip, but that is too long to type.  The default CTM is buried deep in the TB, TextBoxBase IIRC (same menu comes up for the text portion of a CBO).  It is easier to replace them with an empty one than battle with events.

Comment: Yep, I just did that and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to set the [ShortcutsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property of the TextBoxes to False:

> Use the ShortcutsEnabled property to enable or **disable** the
>   following shortcut key combinations and **the control’s shortcut
>   menu**

This disables the keyboard shortcuts as well; not sure if that is applicable to your scenario.

Comment: I don't think it is, but I like the different approach!